# PHPUnit_TextUI_Command test all tests in path without --configuration

Tags: php, phpunit

I am using PHPUnit_TextUI_Command in the following manner

```
$path = 'a/path/to/phpunit.xml';

if(!file_exists($path))
    throw new Exception("Cannot read PHPUnit config file at '" . $path . "'");

$argv = array(
    '--configuration', $path,
);
$_SERVER['argv'] = $argv;

PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main(false);
```

This works fine, but it requires the phpunit.xml configuration file to be present.

What I really want to do is be able to set the directory or file to be tested within my PHP code, rather than in the static phpunit.xml file. Something like this

```
$argv = array(
    '--directory', "a/path/to/tests",
);
$_SERVER['argv'] = $argv;

PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main(false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use

```
$argv = array(
    __FILE__,
    'a/path/to/tests',
);
$_SERVER['argv'] = $argv;
```

If all your case files ends with `Test.php`.

You can change suffix with `--test-suffix` phpunit option.